# Is there any way to detect lowest point of a letter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been playing with JS/jQuery recently and I'm trying to make a physical model of letters with gravity etc. For proper collision of a letter with ground, I need to find coordinates of the lowest point of a rotated letter - the one which touches the bottom of the screen at the moment of collision to calculate angles.

I have an idea which oversimplifies it - to create a rectangular hitbox of the letter, which is known. Actually, for some letters like A, which is fairly triangular, one can design custom shaped hitbox, but it is manual and not exact, and implementing triangle in javascript doesn't seem easy.

I don't need the code, just wanted to hear some ideas, the general approach.

Thank you

Comment: Your idea does not require Jquery, use canvas and create each letter by drawing it on canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use canvas, write letter onto it and then inspect pixels positions and do calculus. Dont know the specs but that way not only could you find the lowest point but also a center of mass and an angle which i can see both as relevant for gravity/ricochet calculation.

Additionally, you might want to pay attention to performance based on number of letters you need for your project.